# Memory comsumption of 22.04 is abnormally high and unstable

Tags: 22.04, vmware, memory-usage

I've been using 22.04 LTS on a VMware virtual machine.
The host OS is macOS 10.15 Catalina and the hardware is iMac Late 2013 (21.5inch).
VMware Fusion is used for the supervisor.

4GB memory is assigned for the virtual machine and the swap is 2GB.

After booting and login,
the system monitor shows about 4GB memory and 800MB swap are used.

On the desktop, 2 gnome terminals are running in addition to the gnome system monitor.
TOP command is runnig in one of the terminals.

Memory usage is abnormally high.
Other than the system monitor and top command, no user job is running.
After left in the idling state for a while,
memory usage abruptly decreases to about 2GB and then goes up to 4GB.

On the other hand, the memory usage of Ubuntu 22.10 on another VMware virtual machine is stable, 2.7GB and about 500MB swap.

Ubuntu 22.04 seems to have some kind of memory handling problem.

Comment: Maybe you want to submit a bug report.

Comment: Yes, I do. What kind of data should I subumit with my bug report? The behaviour of the bug is very volatile so I wonder what data I should log and how I can log it.